# embed audio of youtube playlist

Tags: audio, youtube

I use the following code to embed youtube video's and just show the controls so it only plays the audio:

```
    <object height="25" width="610"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-YhQ7BetDdM&hl=en_US&color1=0xf4f4f4&color2=0xffffff&hd=0&fs=0">
    </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    </param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-YhQ7BetDdM&hl=en_US&color1=0xf4f4f4&color2=0xffffff&hd=0&fs=0" height="25" width="610" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"> </embed>
    </object>
```

I am wondering how to do the same thing but with a playlist of videos? I only want the controls to show.

Comment: disappeared for some reason. I added it again though.

Answer (score -2):

I think this could be what you wanted link ->
[The website](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-audio-player/26740/)

what you need is:

```
 `<div style="position:relative;width:267px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:-276px;left:-5px">
    <iframe width="300" height="300" 
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeID?rel=0">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
`
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Point taking. Sorry that was the first answer I've giving on this site but that's no excuse you do have a point and I'll edit my reply.